# Order of execution for divide,multiply,subtract in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used Addition '+' , Multiplication '*' And Divide '/' operator in my SQL query.
What will be the order of execution for it ?

Query

```
Select A * (B) - C * 100 / (D-E) From Table
```

Comment: Looks like an exam question. [T-SQL operator precedence...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as any other... Based on PEMDAS

```
Parenthesis

Exponents

Multiply 
  and 
Divide at same level, left to right

Add 
  and 
Subtract at same level left to right.




(D-E) is done first
(B) is done next, but is left as-is as no other direct relation 
A * B
C * 100
then 
(result of C * 100) / (D - E result)
(A * B result ) - ( entire C * 100 / (D-E) result)
```

Comment: Except when it doesn't work right: `select 30 / 3 / 5; select 30 / 3 / -5; select 30 / -3 / 5`

Answer (score 0):

Please look below link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

It seems obvious that if two operator have same presedence then expression on left will get more priority. Also expression inside parenthesis will get highest presedence

In your case (D -E) will be evaluated first. Then it will be A * (B) as its on left hand side. Then it will be C * 100.  Then it will be division and last will be substraction.

Let me know if i was correct